# Android: show a folder

Tags: android, directory, storage, external, show

I have a folder saved in external storage in my Android app.
I know to read one file, in this mode:

```
File storage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File file = new File(storage,"/folder/filename.wav");
```

but I want to show all files in folder on my app with the click of a button.

Can you help me, please?

Comment: `show all files in folder on my app with the click of a botton`->too broad

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this:

```
    yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            File file = new File(pathToDirectory);
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            if (file.exists() && file.isDirectory()) {
                for (String s : file.list()) {
                    sb.append(s + " ");
                }
            }
            YourActivity.this.setFileListString(sb.toString());
        }
    });
```

If you want to cycle through the file objects use File instead of String. In your activity you'd need a method that'll write the String into a TextView or something.

Comment: in this way all files, in my folder, will show on activity of my app?

Comment: Switch "yourButton" with your button object.Same goes for YourActivity.